# Getting CodeIgniter RESTful project onto Google App Engine

Tags: codeigniter, google-app-engine

I've used the Codeigniter RESTful framework to make an API for my mobile apps. I would really like to host it on Google's App Engine but there really aren't any tutorials showing how to do this.

Could anybody help in this regard with helping me to get onto app engine?

Answer (score 0):

You can use CodeIgniter modified to run on Google's App Engine (PHP) https://github.com/edwardmp/CodeIgniter-AppEngine

And also follow Tutorial http://blog.programming4design.com/codeigniter-on-google-appengine-for-php/